# How to write regular expressions for JMeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter, ruby-jmeter

As I am new in using jmeter I'm stuck to write regular expression for this expression:

```
/catalog/search_display?category_id=9">Parts</a>
```

Can somebody help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
/catalog/search_display\?category_id=9">Parts</a>
```

Is that what you need? The question mark needs to be escaped, I don't see anything else noteworthy about it. The *JMeter* regexes are not enclosed in `//` and thus the slash is not a special character.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to extract? I assume that it is 9 (category_id). In that case regular expression extractor configuration should look like:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `id`
- Regular Expression: `<a href="/catalog/search_display\?category_id=(.+?)"`
- Template: `$1$`

Refer extracted value as `${id}` where required.

Mention that question mark needs to be escaped by a back slash as it is reserved character in regular expressions.

See  [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter's User Manual for Perl5-style regex syntax and examples.

Also be aware that [it isn't very recommended to parse HTML using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) and it might be better to use the following post processors instead:

- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)